# Align buttons to the left and right in Sencha Touch toolbar

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

**How to align buttons in Sencha Touch toolbars at both sides left and right (one button to each side)?**

In ExtJs I used to use '->'. But this doesn't seem to work in Sencha Touch.

Any ideas ?

EDIT
[image: button image not completely right aligned should appear here]

EDIT
here is my code

```
Ext.define('reestructura.view.ContratoList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'contratolist',
    requires: 'Ext.field.Toggle',
    config: {
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        emptyText: 'El contrato no existe',
        store: 'Contratos',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            style: 'background:darkgray',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'searchfield',
                placeHolder: 'Buscar contrato...'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'search',
                iconMask: true,
                ui: 'confirm',
                action: 'buscarContratos'
            },

            {
                xtype:'spacer'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'togglefield',
                label: 'simulación'
            }
            ]
        }],

        itemTpl : [
        '<p>{idContrato}&nbsp &nbsp {nombreGrupo} </p>',
        '<div style="font-size: 0.75em; color: darkgray">Saldo Pendiente: {saldoPendiente}</div>',  
        ].join('')

    }

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a spacer
Here is an example

```
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Button One'
            }, {
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Button Two'
            }
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I already did but button doesn't go to the end of the toolbar there is some space ...

Comment: This actually works,the problem was that the default width of my togglefield

Answer (score 2):

The following works if you can use a titlebar instead of a toolbar

```
{
     xtype: 'titlebar',
     docked: 'top',
     items: [
         {
             xtype: 'button',
             text: 'Button 1',
             align: 'left'
         },
         {
             xtype: 'button',
             text: 'Button 2',
             align: 'right'
         }
     ]
}
```

If you have to use a toolbar you can try

```
 {
     xtype: 'toolbar',
     docked: 'top',
     items: [
         {
             xtype: 'button',
             text: 'Button 1',
             docked: 'left'
         },
         {
             xtype: 'button',
             text: 'Button 2',
             docked: 'right'
         }
     ]
}
```

But the button text is not center aligned. Modifying the line-height CSS property may fix the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

use '->' between left and right buttons

```
 xtype: 'titlebar',
 dock: 'bottom',
 items: [
     {
         xtype: 'button',
         text: 'Button 1'
     },
     {'->'},
     {
         xtype: 'button',
         text: 'Button 2'
     }
 ]
```